# Php print array help

Tags: php, arrays, printing

I have this array

```
Array ( 
  [3] => Array ( 
     [IDFattura] => 3 
     [Data_Scadenza] => 2011-06-23 
     [Importo] => 343.30 
     [IDTipo_Offerta] => A 
     [Email] => stefano@email.it ) 
  [4] => Array ( 
     [IDFattura] => 4 
     [Data_Scadenza] => 2011-06-23 
     [Importo] => 98.40 
     [IDTipo_Offerta] => A 
     [Email] => stefano@email.it )
  [7] => Array ( 
     [IDFattura] => 33 
     [Data_Scadenza] => 2011-06-23 
     [Importo] => 18.40 
     [IDTipo_Offerta] => A 
     [Email] => tom@email.it ) )
```

Now I need send ONE email to each Email, but stefano@email.it (in email body ) will have a table with two rows, instead of Tom that will have 1 row.
Hope you understand me!

Comment: `stefano@email.it ) )` to `stefano@email.it )`

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($array as $item) $newarray[$item["Email"]] = 1;
$sendarray = array_keys($newarray);
foreach($sendarray as $item) mail(...);
```

you should also consider [array_unique](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should reformat your array like this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $value) {
   $newArray[$value['Email']][] = $value;
}
```

It returns array grouped by Email. And for `stefano@email.it` tou will have an array with 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and group invoices by email:

```
$invoicesByEmail = array();

foreach($invoices as $invoice) {
  if(!isset($invoicesByEmail[$invoice['Email']])) {
    $invoicesByEmail[$invoice['Email']] = array();
  }

  $invoicesByEmail[$invoice['Email']][] = $invoice;
}
```

Then, it's a matter of looping through the grouped invoice and mailing them.

```
foreach($invoicesByEmail as $recipient => $invoices) {
  $emailBody = '';

  foreach($invoices as $invoice) {
    // Parse your invoice
  }

  Mailer::send($recipient, $emailBody, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd structure the array slightly different.  Instead of having numeric keys, i'd set the key as the email address.  This way you can simply use [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

If you **can't** change the array as you get it now, you can loop through it and extract each email address out and insert it into a new array:

```
$uniqueEmails = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $k => $v) { 
  if (isset($v['Email']) $uniqueEmails[$v['Email']] = $v['Email'];
}
return $uniqueEmails;
```